# Querying two many to many relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a users table:

```
id | name
```

I have a role table:

```
id | role
```

I have a user_role pivot table:

```
user_id | role_id
```

I have a permissions table:

```
id | permission
```

I have a role_permissions pivot table:

```
role_id | permission_id
```

A user belongs to many roles.

A role belongs to many users.

A permission belongs to many roles.

How can I query the permissions table, providing a permission and a user id. I basically want to find if a user has a specific permission.

So far I have:

```
$data = Permission::whereHas('roles', function($q){
        //do I need another whereHas here linking roles and users?
    })->where('permission', 'edit')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to just join the tables. There is currently no good way in the framework to achieve this sort of chained relationship.

```
Permission::query()
    ->join('permission_role', 'permission_role.role_id', '=', 'permissions.id')
    ->join('roles', 'roles.id', '=', 'permission_role.role_id')
    ->join('role_user', 'role_user.user_id', '=', 'roles.id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
    ->where('users.whatever', '=', 'something')
    ->where('permissions.permission', '=', 'edit')
    ->get();
```